# Docker randomly restarts all services

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We currently experience intermittent and random restarts of all our Docker swarm services (in production). This behaviour started a couple days ago and so far our services have restarted about 6 times.
When I check `/var/log/messages` we see the following at the moment the services are being restarted

```
Jul 18 14:27:07 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:27:07.777591370+02:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats OUR_MASTER_SERVER(1f6c53091b31) - netID:xqo1jd54dy9h4si7p5kd147lf leaving:false netPeers:2 entries:16 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jul 18 14:27:07 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:27:07.778866829+02:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats OUR_MASTER_SERVER(1f6c53091b31) - netID:hlxpttt1y61naebb1ehva5oa0 leaving:false netPeers:2 entries:42 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jul 18 14:27:07 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:27:07.778894355+02:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats OUR_MASTER_SERVER(1f6c53091b31) - netID:hccgvewpmr4qg93smkf1zb3gk leaving:false netPeers:2 entries:4 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
Jul 18 14:28:05 MASTER_SERVER sshd[64861]: rexec line 25: Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Jul 18 14:28:05 MASTER_SERVER sshd[64861]: rexec line 26: Deprecated option ServerKeyBits
Jul 18 14:28:05 MASTER_SERVER sshd[64861]: rexec line 40: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Jul 18 14:28:05 MASTER_SERVER sshd[64861]: rexec line 42: Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Jul 18 14:28:05 MASTER_SERVER sshd[64861]: rexec line 61: Deprecated option UseLogin
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.219729414+02:00" level=warning msg="memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: b19e7378f796)"
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.242915522+02:00" level=error msg="heartbeat to manager { } failed" error="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = node not registered" method="(*session).heartbeat" module=node/agent node.id=0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8 session.id=mhf0hqu2wo4t6x1n8ja4tzwr3 sessionID=mhf0hqu2wo4t6x1n8ja4tzwr3
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.377485716+02:00" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=100ms error="node not registered" module=node/agent node.id=0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.378175039+02:00" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: { }" module=node/agent node.id=0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.378223959+02:00" level=info msg="waiting 78.699854ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.392797756+02:00" level=info msg="worker 2ni1yglnxjxlpopn7kwxh6oh5 was successfully registered" method="(*Dispatcher).register"
Jul 18 14:28:37 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:37.497010348+02:00" level=info msg="worker 0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8 was successfully registered" method="(*Dispatcher).register"
Jul 18 14:28:39 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: rr: FWM 452 0x000001C4 - no destination available
Jul 18 14:28:39 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: rr: FWM 452 0x000001C4 - no destination available
Jul 18 14:28:39 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: rr: FWM 451 0x000001C3 - no destination available
Jul 18 14:28:40 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452920.8734] manager: (veth33d0b84): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1919)
Jul 18 14:28:40 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452920.8750] manager: (veth1ba455b): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1920)
Jul 18 14:28:40 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 2(veth260) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:40 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 2(veth260) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:40 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth260 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452921.0567] manager: (veth9b724a9): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1921)
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452921.0604] manager: (veth328f5ab): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1922)
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth83) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth83) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth83 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth83) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth83) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41+02:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=af9c57b5a3e15cf84eb6c11e81b9b1283c86d289819600ddd83fd5cf791141cf module="containerd/tasks"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41+02:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=08e21510d82e56462f4bcfe5e4d734c8fcf21c92470afcf711bca5c7b1a29e88 module="containerd/tasks"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41.126973723+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41.127491897+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41.128341866+02:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 208e26beb7581a7e09041ebf23d6170f0f7ad7785a28b0d5b37b4194cca8d64e possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41+02:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=99889097e3444a485567d85d5dcdbd1f56c49369207f3137d7c80d7c8efd1168 module="containerd/tasks"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41.132298072+02:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding 055c400762be47b9e7c09c3a948c17b049a91b0cb53fbcefaee5f48f448fb91a possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:41.140787013+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452921.1487] manager: (veth7b97007): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1923)
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth83) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:41 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 16(veth257) entered disabled state
...
MORE OF THE SAME
...
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 7(veth82) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth82 left promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 7(veth82) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 17(veth7648a95) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth7648a95 left promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 17(veth7648a95) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:54 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452934.9971] device (veth7648a95): released from master device docker_gwbridge
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 15(veth256) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth256 left promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 15(veth256) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth865a1b5) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth865a1b5) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth865a1b5 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 11(veth253) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:55+02:00" level=error msg="setting up rule failed, [-t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.155/32 -j MARK --set-mark 458]:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.155/32 -j MARK --set-mark 458: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n (exit status 1))"
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth253 left promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 11(veth253) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:55 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:55.049845009+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete firewall mark rule in sbox e6c95a7 (16cba4b): reexec failed: exit status 5"
... 
MORE OF THIS
...
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.877371310+02:00" level=warning msg="rmServiceBinding a22765c0f00db0a4949b009129fa3efc78e2450567e759ff306dcfd32ebe0043 possible transient state ok:false entries:0 set:false "
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.893365848+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete real server 10.0.0.124 for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox f9cd880 (f0562de): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.893415513+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete service for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox f9cd880 (f0562de): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9029] device (veth8339f31): carrier: link connected
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth8339f31) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth8339f31) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9250] device (veth242a19a): carrier: link connected
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth242a19a) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 5(veth242a19a) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth08b162c) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 6(veth08b162c) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9454] device (veth08b162c): carrier: link connected
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9647] device (veth1c69a54): carrier: link connected
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57+02:00" level=error msg="setting up rule failed, [-t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.161/32 -j MARK --set-mark 455]:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.161/32 -j MARK --set-mark 455: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n (exit status 1))"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.975416212+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete firewall mark rule in sbox f9cd880 (f0562de): reexec failed: exit status 5"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.975578597+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete real server 10.0.0.124 for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox fd62ef8 (7801a00): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:57.975609232+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete service for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox fd62ef8 (7801a00): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 14(veth1c69a54) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 14(veth1c69a54) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth865a1b5) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 2(veth865a1b5) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9814] device (veth865a1b5): carrier: link connected
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9902] manager: (veth90d68ef): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1988)
Jul 18 14:28:57 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452937.9937] manager: (veth1c52f1f): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1989)
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth713fa85) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth713fa85) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth713fa85 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth713fa85) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 9(veth713fa85) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452938.0130] manager: (vethdc96c98): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1990)
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER NetworkManager[8489]: <info>  [1563452938.0142] manager: (veth713fa85): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1991)
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth269) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth269) entered disabled state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: device veth269 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth269) entered blocking state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: br0: port 4(veth269) entered forwarding state
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58+02:00" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/5cadb3994f4d81174c1b686028a6fd3e917c9b8b2ac62b17c4754e59ed4a2158/shim.sock" debug=false module="containerd/tasks" pid=2290
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58+02:00" level=info msg="shim docker-containerd-shim started" address="/containerd-shim/moby/536c3eae39192936e649668192e0daf6efba70cc60d1822cd0e8e2e593ebac40/shim.sock" debug=false module="containerd/tasks" pid=2300
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: Creating netns size=2048 id=305
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58+02:00" level=error msg="setting up rule failed, [-t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.161/32 -j MARK --set-mark 455]:  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t mangle -D OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.161/32 -j MARK --set-mark 455: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n (exit status 1))"
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58.283086156+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete firewall mark rule in sbox fd62ef8 (7801a00): reexec failed: exit status 5"
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58.283246626+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete real server 10.0.0.124 for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox b828388 (4152113): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER dockerd: time="2019-07-18T14:28:58.283277874+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to delete service for vip 10.0.0.161 fwmark 455 in sbox b828388 (4152113): no such process"
Jul 18 14:28:58 MASTER_SERVER kernel: IPVS: Creating netns size=2048 id=306
```

When I check the services with `docker service ps qbrek329yydx`
I see that previous containers have the desired state "Shutdown". When I inspect the stopped containers, they have either exited with status 0 or status 137

Status 0:

```
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-07-18T12:29:03.540071095Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2019-07-18T14:32:57.229648337Z"
    }
```

Status 137:

```
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 137,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-07-18T12:29:00.047740568Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2019-07-18T14:33:07.497580769Z",
        "Health": {
            "Status": "unhealthy",
            "FailingStreak": 0,
```

Those with status 137 are normal, because if our RabbitMQ stops, Spring will report that it's unhealthy and Docker will try to restart. The containers are not killed by OOM, the applications inside did not crash, Docker just decided to restart everything.

We also have containers deployed without swarm, those are never restarted and are still up and running since long time. It's only those containers which have been created with a docker service which are being restarted. This also indicates that the docker daemon hasn't restarted either.

We first assumed it was a network issue (causing RabbitMQ to fail and our healthchecks to cause restartes, but even our filebeat container which has no healthcheck gets restarted), in the mean time we have applied the SACK Kernel panic attack mitigation and [these fixes](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32195#issuecomment-356835085) but without any luck.

We still have enough disk space, so that's not the problem either. We're a bit low on memory, but nothing which would cause a crash

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         11G        1.3G        183M        2.5G        3.2G
Swap:          4.0G        258M        3.7G
```

The output of `docker info` is

```
Containers: 54
 Running: 14
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 40
Images: 48
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 0bf0j7rcw6xg7pda5lka7jyy8
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 0e4yg9p17skhonx5jkaulhrsi
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.242.171.24
 Manager Addresses:
  10.242.171.24:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 15.5GiB
Name: OUR_MASTER_SERVER
ID: OZOG:AM6N:XGRS:KZMV:BOHR:QGAX:625X:AFDW:F6AV:P7ZF:FS4R:TCZL
Docker Root Dir: /opt/hpc/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Does anyone have a clue why we get all these restarts ?

Comment: have same problem in swarm with 3 managers

Answer (score 1):

For me was my backup routine in VMs running Docker Swarm. Backup routine cut the service for some seconds, a bunch of logs like this popout in the screen + services connecting to this service running in the VM are disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is related to your network connectivity, because of `heartbeat to manager { } failed`.

```
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
```

When it is true, you got only one manager node and two worker nodes?
The manager node will restart (I guess again) all containers after reconnecting to its nodes to fullfill the service definitions.

For productive workloads, you should have at least three docker swarm managers. This will make the cluster more fault tolerant.
When your cluster consists only of three nodes, promote the two worker nodes also to managers.

Comment: Unfortunately, we currently only have one manager and one worker node (the manager is also a worker node). I could understand why the manager would want to restart everything on the worker node, but I don't understand why it's restarting everything on itself too.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a lot more digging, put our production nodes in debug mode and checked the logs. 
In debug mode, Docker outputs a log message about every 1-2 seconds and I noticed multiple gaps in the logs, some of the gaps were 5 seconds long but sometimes I would not get any log message for over 20 seconds after which Docker would consider the master node (itself) as unstable and it forced itself to restart, pulling all other instances with it (the downside of having one master).

After migrating our VM to another server, the problem never re-occurred and it's running fine again. We've ordered a 3rd VM so we can run with 3 masters so that we can survive a single master failure.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar situation with a 3-node swarm (Ubuntu 20.04 server) running as VMs inside Microsoft Failover Cluster.

This is caused by backup operation, which for a brief period interrupts networking of the VM which is being backed-up.

To understand what exactly happening we need to look at logs on all docker swarm nodes:

### Logs @ swarm node being backed-up

Let's first look at logs on a VM which was backed-up:

```
# This log indicates that the Docker Swarm node received a "suspect" message from another node.
level=warning msg="memberlist: Refuting a suspect message (from: cb327e9e8062)"

# This log entry indicates a failure in sending a heartbeat signal to a manager node. It suggests a network or communication issue, possibly due to a timeout.
level=error msg="heartbeat to manager { } failed" error="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" method="(*session).heartbeat" module=node/agent node.id=xaakvjqrfkhfr2mbe4dkg7gus session.id=0r44stbs8ofp0715oz82dn28m sessionID=0r44stbs8ofp0715oz82dn28m

# This message confirms that the node cb327e9e8062 is suspected to have failed because no acknowledgments (acks) were received.
level=info msg="memberlist: Suspect cb327e9e8062 has failed, no acks received"

# This indicates a successful registration of a worker node in the Docker Swarm cluster.
level=info msg="worker u7whvivqi809wrjo5y2mgnbq3 was successfully registered" method="(*Dispatcher).register"

# This entry shows that an agent experienced a session failure, likely related to the earlier heartbeat failure. The system is backing off for 100 milliseconds before retrying.
level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=100ms error="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded" module=node/agent node.id=xaakvjqrfkhfr2mbe4dkg7gus

# This indicates that the agent has selected a manager for establishing a new session, part of the retry mechanism following the session failure.
level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: { }" module=node/agent node.id=xaakvjqrfkhfr2mbe4dkg7gus

# This log entry suggests a brief delay before the agent attempts to register a new session, following the backoff strategy.
level=info msg="waiting 88.328016ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=xaakvjqrfkhfr2mbe4dkg7gus
```

These logs collectively indicate typical activities in a Docker Swarm environment, including node communication, heartbeat signaling, session management, and worker registration, as well as handling of potential issues such as communication timeouts and node failures.

Also this machine reported the following message:

```
dockerd[1036]: time="2023-12-01T00:04:30.911132583+01:00" level=error msg="[resolver] failed to query DNS server: 192.168.1.10:53, query: ;bshots.egcvi.com.\tIN\t A" error="read udp 172.18.0.15:53870->192.168.1.10:53: i/o timeout"
```

This confirms that the node is having connectivity issues

### Logs @ node not being backed-up

Now let's have a look at swarm node which was operating normally:

```
dockerd: level=info msg="Node 488678db26c1/192.168.1.88, left gossip cluster"
dockerd: level=info msg="Node 488678db26c1 change state NodeActive --> NodeFailed"
dockerd: level=info msg="Node 488678db26c1/192.168.1.88, added to failed nodes list"
dockerd: level=info msg="Node 488678db26c1/192.168.1.88, joined gossip cluster"
```

These logs collectively indicate that the node which was backed-up was unavailable and was marked as `Failed`.

Logs also contain the following messages:

```
kernel: IPVS: rr: FWM 626 0x00000272 - no destination available
```

These indicate that the IP Virtual server which does load balancing of incoming traffic among swarm nodes could not reach one of the nodes (the one which was backed-up).

After the connection was re-established the following log message was recorded:

```
level=info msg="Node 488678db26c1 change state NodeFailed --> NodeActive"
```

### Conclusion

The back-up operation causes an interruption in networking. Docker Swarm is sensitive to this kind of interruptions. In such cases it marks the problematic node as `Failed` and begins *moving* containers/services from to the healthy nodes. We see this as containers/services being restarted.

### Solution

As of this moment we're still searching for a solution to this problem.

At least we know why this is happening.